# Entering iOS and Android programming

Tags: android, c++, ios, qt

I searched the web and apparently there isn't any concrete conclusion on how and why I should start that new way.

I'm a C++ programmer. What I have studied so far, has been on the console apps but in a near future I'll go on Qt as a DEL for creating real graphical C++ apps.

Because of the markets demand (from where I live), I want to enter the way of learning the creating iOS and Android apps. As I said about my studies on C++, I have some basic skills obtained from that great language, C++, so, that new way sounds easy to follow to me.

Now, I'd like to ask you expert programmers some questions based on your experiences for guiding and directing me into the correct path.

1- Is it possible (or better) to use the C++ itself, for creating iOS and Android apps?
2- If the answer to the question #1 is no, what is the way your recommend me for that aim?
3- The way I've learnt C++ has been by books and practicing on MS Visual Studio IDE. If I'm advised to go to a different field (different from C++) for programming those apps, I like to use books. If you agree, what books do you suggest for programming those apps that are good for my abilities.
Thanks.

Comment: This is primarily opinion based I think - it depends on how familiar individual developers are with each specific approach. Both using native code (Java/Swift) or another language via a cross-platform toolkit (e.g. Qt) are valid approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Qt5 make it really easy to deploy [Android](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/android-support.html) and [iOS](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/ios-support.html) application fully written in C++.

If you want to stick with C++ programming, it's definitley a very nice option to use QtCreator IDE.

Comment: It's really appreciable that I don't have to change my current way (on C++)! Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You'll find some limitations when trying to access low level hardware functionnalities or gestures, but Qt team is adding more support to those one every new release!

Comment: I really like to start on Qt right now but, there are two issues. 1- I'm not at that level yet. 2- The book Mr. stroustrup recommended me (the following one) seems to be somewhat old. It speaks about Qt 4.3 http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Edition-Prentice-Software-Development/dp/0132354160

Answer (score 1):

> 1- Is it possible (or better) to use the C++ itself, for creating iOS and Android apps?

As an answer to this question, yes. C++ is used in the [Cocos2d-x](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/) framework, for instance, which is the game engine written in C++. It uses OpenGL API to draw view on iPhone/Android. With OpenGL, you can draw anything with C++.

Also, for iPhone apps, you can build apps C++ and Objective-C, which is the language called Objective-C++. With that, you can use C++ and you can call functions provided by Cocoa SDKs made by Apple. For android apps, you can use NDK and you can call functions provided on Android with C++.

My recommendation is studying how to build iPhone apps with Objective-C++. You need to study little Objective-C, but if you are pretty matured for C++, it is really easy to learn Objective-C. Many C++ developers learned how to build mobile apps and are building iPhone apps by doing so.

Comment: You talked about some high-level matters like OpenGL that since I'm rather novice I couldn't take advantages of these. But you said that I can use C++ for my purposes. If I don't have to, I don't like to enter a new way and leave out C++ although for a while. Thank you for your answer.